# The perimeter of a segment of a circle is 22 inches. The arc is 2 radians. What is the area of the segment?

Tags: trigonometry, area

The perimeter of a segment of a circle is 22 inches. The arc is 2 radians. What is the area of the segment?

I am having a hard time answering this question since the given are the perimeter of the segment as well as the arc measure. On the other hand, I am positive that the answer can be found using the given but I don't know-how. Can you please help me? It will be a big help. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to figure out the **radius** of the circle, based on the given information. Remember to also draw a picture of the situation.

Comment: How can I get the radius of the circle using the given? May you enlighten me please? Thank you.

Comment: Draw a picture of the segment. I think it looks like a pizza slice. What are the side lengths of the segment? Well, two of them are equal to the radius $r$, and the arc length is $\frac{2}{2\pi} r$. We know that the sum of these three should equal to $22$ inches ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be a radius of the circle.

Thus, $$2r\sin1+2r=22,$$ which gives $$r=\frac{11}{1+\sin1}.$$
Id est, the are of the segment is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\left(\frac{11}{1+\sin1}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{11}{1+\sin1}\right)^2\sin2=\left(\frac{11}{1+\sin1}\right)^2(1-\sin1\cos1).$$